# Difference between a flat and a "ball-like" hand on piano

Tags: piano, technique, keyboard, synthesizer, posture

I'm not sure if the hand posture is called "ball-like" in English, but is there a difference in playing, technique and/or something else between a balled-hand and a flat one?; (most rock and synth) keyboard players have that.

Comment: A synth keyboard isn't a piano keyboard. Once you get past the trivial statement of "you play them both by pressing the keys down" the techniques are very different.

Comment: Holding your hand ball-like is necessary to gain control over sound and precision in chords. This doesn't really come up in rock or synth playing, while in classical playing this is required.

Comment: I think you're talking about having the fingers more flat versus curled when playing the piano. I've seen famous pianists use both hand positions. My guess is that it depends on the demands of the particular passage. For example, a wider stretch will require flatter fingers to get the most distance, while a very fast trill seems to be best executed with curled fingers.

Comment: @11684 So could you answer, what the difference is.

Comment: @ToddWilcox You may be right, yet, I've seen musicians choose particulary one over the other.

Comment: This guy starts off clearly curled and then he flattens his hands out a bit. Is that what you're asking about? https://youtu.be/-P8BQVhOv5A

Comment: Just to be clear: by "ball-like" you mean: as though the fingers were wrapped around a ball, right?

Comment: @Dave Exactly! That's all about curliness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was a piano teacher for over 50 years before I retired recently, and it is my experience that no two hands are alike and no two pianists ever use exactly the same hand technique.. Success comes from finding what works for YOUR hand, and to listen to supposed 'expert' teachers lecture about 'correct' hand posture is to invite carpal tunnel syndrome.

One of the greatest pianists I ever met was Claudio Arrau.  He played with absolutely flat hands, no finger curl or 'ball shape' at all.  Yet he played with great control and a huge range of dynamics and total control of touch.  I've met other pianists who play with perfect 'hold the ball while playing' technique who are very very good.  But none of them are as good as Arrau.  Find the hand posture that works for you, that gives you the best touch control and range of dynamics, and use that posture.  Your hands will let you know.

Hope that helps.